# Pass array of ids to custom get in Restangular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restangular

I'm trying to pass an array of ids to my server using Restangular

```
var params = { profile_ids: _.map(fof, 'id') }
Restangular.all('mutual_friends').customGET('', params)
```

however, this results in the following query string being passed the my rails server

```
Started GET "/mutual_friends?profile_ids=231&profile_ids=2&profile_ids=254
```

how can I send the ids as an array? so the query string looks like:

```
/mutual_friends?profile_ids=[231, 2, 354]
```

Comment: can you use `post` instead of `get`?

Comment: Try `var params = { 'profile_ids[]': _.map(fof, 'id') }`